# Add elements of a list together

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

When I use the command

```
f.readline()[34:42].split()
```

I get the list `['00', '36', '52']`.

I would like to:

1. First multiply the single elements with different factors
2. Then add them together.

But what do I have to do to add them and get 88?

When I try

```
int(f.readline()[34:42].split()[0]) + int(f.readline()[34:42].split()[1]) + int(f.readline()[34:42].split()[2])
```

It goes to the next line of the file and it doesn't add the 3 numbers of the same line, which I want to add together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f.readline()` will not read the same line each time. Files have a reading position, and every time you read something that position advances.

Store the line you read in a variable first, *then* operate on that. You can store the result of the split in a variable too, so you don't have to keep splitting:

```
line = f.readline()
numbers = line[34:42].split()
result = int(numbers[0]) + int(numbers[1]) + int(numbers[2])
```

The important section here is to call `f.readline()` just the one time. You can combine the above in to a one-liner that does all the work in one go:

```
result = sum(int(number) for number in f.readline()[34:42].split())
```

which can be a bit more daunting to parse if you are new to the language, but that still reads and splits the line just once, and then processes the resulting elements from the split in a loop before adding them all together with the [`sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Now I have another little question:
My file has many lines with elements I want to add together, but now when I run my programm with `running = True` and `while running: print` it does only print the result of the first line infinite times, but I want it to go through all the lines of the entire file. What do I have to do?

Comment: Don't use `while running`; just use `for line in f:` and use the `line` variable. The loop will give you each line in the file one by one until the file is done.

Comment: `for line in f: print(sum(int(number) for number in line[34:42].split())`

Comment: So I just tried this:
`f=open('ULIRGs.txt')

line = f.readline()
numbers = line[34:42].split()
result = 15*int(numbers[0]) + 0.25*int(numbers[1]) + 0.0041666666*int(numbers[2])


for line in f:
    print result`

But it doesn't work. It just prints the same result (of the first line) for each line... What did I do wrong?

Comment: @PaulFalkland: Python doesn't recalculate `result` for you each time in the loop, no. Remove the `f.readline()` call, you don't use that at all when using a `for line in f:` loop. Put everything else *in* the loop so you calculate `result` for each line.

Comment: Now it worked, thank you very much for taking your time to help me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator expression to convert all the values to `int`, then `sum` the result.

```
>>> l = ['00', '36', '52']
>>> sum(int(i) for i in l)
88
```

If you want to multiply them by a factor, you can just do so externally

```
>>> factor = 3
>>> sum(int(i) for i in l) * factor
264
```

This works because multiplication is commutative (and the distributive property). In other words

```
n*a + n*b + n*c == n*(a + b + c)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using readline() three times. Do it once and store it in a variable.
like this:

```
list1 = f.readline()[34:42].split()
print sum(map(int,list1))
```

Anytime you use fileobject.readline() the file seek position will move to next line, after returning the current line.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the output you get from `f.readline()[34:42].split()` in a variable at first and then `map` them and get the sum of it

```
>>> l = f.readline()[34:42].split() # Stores ['00', '36', '52'] in l
>>> sum (map(int,l))
88
```

Note- The next time you use `readline` it will read the next line

Refer

- [`sum` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)
- [`map` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)